# What is Java equivalent of $ curl --upload-file $uploadFileName $upload_url

Tags: java, android, curl, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a zip file on amazon S3 bucket using android. But the specification I have for the upload is shown using

`curl --upload-file  $uploadFileName $upload_url`  command

I am at the moment using:

```
int TIMEOUT_MILLISEC = 300000;  // = 5 mints
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uploadURL);
entity.addPart("uploadedfile", new FileBody((sourceFile), "application/zip"));
httppost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = null;
response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
```

in AsyncTask().
There is some progress shown instantly like 30-40% on progress bar but then

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x7f6f071b80: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
```

What is the reason for this error. Is there any other way to upload zip file on to server because using

```
curl --upload-file
```

it is working (according to server side people) and I want to implement this upload functionality using Android.

Comment: I tried using HttpPut instead of HttpPost, it uploaded to 100% on progress bar. But there is a 403 ERROR code in response.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick Google I found some information about it. It means that the pipe to the server is broken; in other words: the server closes the connection. This can be due a **too big file upload**. Could you verify that the file is not too big for the upload or try some other (perhaps smaller) file?

Comment: I tried what you said. I got javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x769c9fc800: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer on full zip of around 4 mb and HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden when i reduced its size to 70 Kb.

Comment: Did you set the correct region for uploading the to amazon? If you are connecting to the wrong region it will redirect you to the correct one (and will kill your current connection)

Comment: I understand your point but i am uploading the zip through S3 upload url which i receive from json. So does it still matter ?